# aop not worked while proceeding in another aspect

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop

there are two aspects : ControllerRequestAspect and StockCamponLogAspect.
ControllerRequestAspect advices the controller-level bean and it is proxied by cglib.
StockCamponLogAspect advices the service-level bean and it is proxied by jdk dynamic proxy.

the problem is : normal http request can be detected by ControllerRequestAspect's pointcut, but the followed service method can't be detected by StockCamponLogAspect's pointcut while it can be detected by junit test.

So, how can i activate the advice of the StockCamponLogAspect while its upper invoker is another proxy (enhanced by cglib) ?

here is the code from controller :

```
@RequestMapping({ "/verifyTransfer" })
@ResponseBody
public JsonResult<Map<String, Object>> agentSaleVerify(Integer transferId, String name, Integer verifyResult, String verifyContent) throws Exception {
    return agentSaleExpotService.agentSaleVerify(transferId, name, verifyResult, verifyContent)
}
```

here is the code from junit test :

```
@Test
@StockCampon
public void updateReleaseNumByStockIdTest() {
    Map<String, Object> params = Maps.newHashMap();
    params.put("stockId", 2646);
    params.put("stockStatus", 1);
    params.put("operQualifiedOn", 5);
    int num = stockMapper.updateReleaseNumByStockId(params);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post additional code: pointcuts config, advice, etc...

Comment: solved...it was my mistake, it not the springmvc.xml, but the applicationContext-service.xml need to add the following code : <context:component-scan base-package="com.huizhuang.scm.aop" use-default-filters="false">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component"/>
 </context:component-scan>
 
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>